# Caixa de texto executar função quando for atribuído externamente um valor a ela em Javascript e HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Queria fazer uma caixa de texto executar uma função quando eu atribuir um valor a ela por código, sem interação com usuário.

Já tentei os eventos `onChange`, `onInput`, `onKeypress`, porém todos eles dependem do contato do usuário com a caixa de texto.

Segue abaixo o meu progresso com minha duvida, quando aperto o botao "Validar" é atribuído externamente "123" a uma caixa de texto e a minha funcao ãno identifica a variação da caixa de texto e não executa a função, ela executa somente quando o usuario interage com ela.

```html
<form action="" name="f1">  
  <label>Comparar valores <BR>(Valores iguais = PRETO, Valores diferentes=VERMELHO)</label> <br>
  <input type="text" id="pass" oninput="Verifica()"/>
<input type="text" id="pass2"  oninput="Verifica()"/>
<script>
function Verifica(){
    val1=document.getElementById("pass").value;
    val2=document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    if(val1!=val2){
    document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor="#f00";
        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="#f00";
    }
    else{document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor="#000";
        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="#000";

        }
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Validar" onClick="validarSenha()">

<script>
function validarSenha(){
 document.getElementById("pass2").value = "123"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Mas por que você não chama a função que quer no mesmo código que atribui o valor?

Comment: Porque este código simula uma resposta externa de um iframe, nao consigo alterar nada dele, eu so consigo pegar seu feedback

Comment: Me parece impossível ou inviável. Veja essa resposta aqui, se entende inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848008/1796236

Comment: Não sei se o que quero fazer pode ser considerado uma "solução elegante", mas acredito que é a unica forma de conseguir o que preciso, porque estou limitado ao servidor acima de mim, quero realmente saber se é possivel fazer isto, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Tentou o focusout? https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: Tem algumas soluções com css senão me engano.

Comment: user5988, O focusout se não me engano depende de interação com o usuário, e queria que esta verificação da caixa de texto seja feito 100% via código

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>       
        <form action="" name="f1">  
            <label>Comparar valores <BR>(Valores iguais = PRETO, Valores diferentes=VERMELHO)</label> <br>
            <input type="text" id="pass" oninput="Verifica()"/>
            <input type="text" id="pass2"  oninput="Verifica()"/>
            <script>
                function Verifica(){
                    val1=document.getElementById("pass").value;
                    val2=document.getElementById("pass2").value;
                    if(val1 != val2){
                        document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor="#f00";
                        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="#f00";
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor="#000";
                        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="#000";
                    }
                };
            </script>
            <input type="button" value="Validar" onClick="validarSenha()"/>

            <script>
                function validarSenha(){
                    senha1 = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                    senha2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
                    document.getElementById("pass2").value = "123";
                    if (senha2  != document.getElementById("pass2").value){
                        if (senha1 == senha2)
                            alert("SENHAS IGUAIS");
                    else
                        alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES");
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não esqueça de dar um reload na pagina quando vc quiser testar novamente, até porque quando você aciona o botão validar, é a ação que você está esperando que ocorra, se analisar o teu código você verificará que o problema está na aclopação de funções entre envento e lógica de validação ;-)

Comment: TiagoTI, o que eu espero que aconteca com o codigo e que se eu digitar "123" da caixa de texto 1 e pressionar o botão "Validar" será adicionado automaticamente "123" na caixa de texto 2, com isto a borda das caixas  de texto deveria ficar preta, sinalizando valores iguais

Comment: O botão validar só teria a funcao de adicionar "123" na caixa de texto

Comment: @VitorMarquesLourenço Então não foca no evento das caixa de texto não, foque no método Validar:
Passo 1 pegar o valor da caixa de texto1. 
Passo 2 verificar se configurar a caixa  de texto2 para 123. 
Passo 3 verificar se o valor 123 é igual ao da caixa de texto1. 
Passo 4 colorir conforme o resultado. 
Se você focar evento vai ser complicado porque o seu algoritmo do Validar não vai esperar um evento da caixa de texto acontecer para validar (isso é uma caracteristica do JavaScript).

Comment: TiagoTi vc esta falando para eu chamar a funcao validar direto no botao? Desta forma funciona, porém no meu caso em especifico eu nao posso focar no botao validar, pq nao posso alterar ele, pois o codigo dele esta em um servidor acima de mim, nao tenho acesso a ele, so recebo seu feedback na caixa de texto

Comment: Será que é possível eu criar uma funcao que rode automaticamente no fundo sempre e a cada 1 segundo por exemplo ele faz uma verificacao na caixa de texto e compara se o valor foi alterado?

Comment: É sim tem como, mas é inviavél pois gastarar tempo de cpu desnecessário ... uma dúvida tens como explicar melhor este lance de um servidor acima ?

Comment: Eu quero aproveitar um feedback de um objeto, este objeto imprime o estado dele em um textbox, o problema é q este objeto está hospedado em um servidor onde nao tenho acesso, o unico contato que eu tenho com ele é atraves deste textbox, eu posso analizar o estado deste objeto analizando o texto da textbox

Comment: Como você faz contato com esse servidor, você pode usar o próprio callback para fazer a verificação, imagino que você deva está usando ajax seria isso ?

Comment: Vish nao manjo esta area de ajax, mas nao acredito que exista outra forma de obter esta informacao do servidor, ja falei com os responsaveis pelo servidor e eles falaram que por questoes de seguranca o servidor e fechado, acredito entao que e somente pela textbox mesmo